# iTerm 2 won't let me change the theme with zsh

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I installed all the required packages for zsh and Iterm 2 to run, but when I try to change the theme with `ZSH_THEME` the terminal says `/Users/Brandon/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:source:110: no such file or directory: /Users/Brandon/.oh-my-zsh/themes/“mh”.zsh-theme`. Even though the theme is there and installed. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: As a wild guess, I'm going to say the problem probably lies with those fancy quotes (`“` and `”`) you're using to specify the file. I'm betting you don't actually have a file with those in the name. Those fancy quotes are not the same characters as the regular quotes (`"`). Making this a comment for now as it's entirely possible you actually do have an oddly named file with the fancy quotes.

Comment: It auto changes to the fancy quotes every time I change the file name

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Comment: It was opening in Text Edit but when I changed it to open in Atom Text Editor it worked and I was able to change the theme! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I'll move it to a proper answer, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably lies with those fancy quotes (`“` and `”`) you're using to specify the file. I'm betting you don't actually have a file with those in the name. Those fancy quotes are not the same characters as the regular quotes (`"`).

Check your text editor's settings for any quote replacing options, or switch to another text editor. On MacOS, I believe both Vim and Nano should be available through the terminal without any extra installations, and both should reliably use the proper quote characters.